# How can I fix this program while still keeping my abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I am confused about how to keep my Tractor class abstract while still letting me testTractor class to perform its functions.

testTractor.java:9: error: Tractor is abstract; cannot be instantiated
      Tractor testT = new Tractor();

```
public class testTractor
       {
       public static void main (String[] args)
         {    
          Tractor testT = new Tractor();
          testT.setName("TractorTest");
          testT.setVehicleID(5450);
          testT.setRentalDays(25);
          testT.setRentalRate(40);
          System.out.println("Tractor Name: " + testT.getName());
          System.out.println("Vehicle ID: " + testT.getVehicleID());
          System.out.println("Rental Days: " + testT.getRentalDays());
          System.out.println("Rental Rate: " + testT.getRentalRate());
         }
```

Comment: Don't you need to show us your Tractor class code for us to be able to help in any reasonable way?

Comment: You must implement the abstract functionality of `Tractor` either via a separate class or inline

Comment: I think you should approach this problem without an abstract class but that  is a complete guess since you haven't posted any code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd guess your `TestTractor` class should `extend` your `Tractor` class. Then you can keep your `Tractor` class abstract while still being able to treat your instances of `TestTractor` as `Tractor` objects when that's convenient. You'll also want to only call the constructor for the `TestTractor` class. Remember that Google is your friend, and there are tons of examples to look at.

Comment: `TestTractor` must `extends` abstract class `Tractor`. Then initialize abstract class as `Tractor tractor = new TestTractor();`. Because abtract class can not initialized.

Comment: Important note @LES, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class cannot be instantiated. The idea behind an abstract class is to define a specification of common attributes and functions (with optional default implementations) that different but related classes can have. What you could do is create a subclass that inherits from the abstract Tractor class. That way you can run its functions while keeping it abstract.

Comment: Thank You for your help.